# How to make manifest.json code to html code for web server?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I have a auto bot chrome extension and I want to make it an online web version and want to make it a html version for my web server. Now Auto bot start as a chrome extension but I want to start it from my website.

Extension all codes are js and css but only one code manifest.json different.

How can I make it web version?

Here is the manifest json Code:

```
{
"background": {"scripts": ["js/jquery.js","js/background.js"]},
"description": "auto bot",
"homepage_url": "http://example.com",
"author": "Mąşųd Rąŋą",
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Auto Tools",
"icons": {"128": "icon.png"},
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "Auto Extension"
},
"permissions": [
    "storage",
    "management",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "webNavigation",
    "tabs",
    "proxy",
    "cookies",
    "notifications",
    "*://*/*",
    "activeTab",
    "browsingData",
    "contextMenus",
    "clipboardWrite",
    "clipboardRead",
    "downloads"
],
"content_scripts": [
 {
   "matches": [
    "*://*.facebook.com/*"
   ],
  "js": [
    "js/jquery.js",
    "js/autobot.js"
   ],
  "css": [
  "css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
  "run_at": "document_end",
  "all_frames": false
}],
"update_url": "http://example.com",
"version": "1.0",
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
 }
```

Please help me to make it server/web version.

Sorry for not good english. thanks